# How to change matching elements inside arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry for the question but i am starting with coding and i have this problem, and i am stuck, if you could give some help would be great.
So the problem is I have two variables with arrays.
Like this:
Var names1 = [
Rui,
Jose, 
Carlos,
Miguel];

Var names 2 = [
Rui,
Tiago,
Jose, 
Carlos,
Rogerio]

And I need to find the names that match in names1 with names2, and change them only in names2 do other random names of my choosing.
To find them I am doing

```
    For ( var I = 0; I < names1.length ; i++);
For ( var j = 0; j < names2.length ; j++);
If ( names1[i] = names2[j]){
```

The next part I have no idea what to do.
I though about deleting them and then add them.
But I don’t think it’s the best solution.
Can u help?

Comment: What language are you using?  JavaScript?

Comment: I am using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps! 
Basically you look through both arrays and then compare them at all indexes.
If there is a match, you change the name for the names2 element.

```js
var names1 = ["Rui", "Jose", "Carlos", "Miguel"];

var names2 = ["Rui", "Tiago", "Jose", "Carlos", "Rogerio"];

var randomNames = ["Bob", "Goerge", "Maria", "Carrie"];

for (var i = 0; i < names1.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < names2.length; j++) {
    
    if (names1[i] == names2[j]) {
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNames.length);
      names2[j] = randomNames[random];
      
    }
    
  }
}

console.log(names2);
```

**So I added the functionality where it replaces the duplicated name with random ones from the randomNames array. **

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but if i change it that way i can only put one string or else they will all print out in the same line,

Comment: Any way to print them in different lines like the original one??